Missing parent with expo-router navigation and react-navigation
Using expo-router, expo 51, react native, etc.
I have the following navigation structure
Tab bar

/home
/(messages)
/(messages)/[userId]
/profile

There are cases where you can tap on something in /home, and the app will navigate you to /messages/[id] using:
navigation.navigate('(messages)', {
   screen: '[userId]',
   params: {
       userId: message.user.id,
   },
});

and the (messages)/_layout.tsx
export default function MessagesTab() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" />
      <Stack.Screen name="[userId]" options={{
        headerBackTitle: 'Messages',
      }} />
    </Stack>
  );
};

This works as expected. However, if the user NEVER tapped on the Messages tab prior to taking this action, /messages will not exist in the navigation stack, and will become unreachable.
I'm trying to have the following:
(messages)/index is pushed onto the stack, if does not exist, when the slug is pushed. This way, the back bar item always shows regardless of if you've tapped on the tab or not.

It's a bit buried in the documentation, because the ordering of initial seems to matter if its before or after params.
navigation.navigate('(messages)', {
                screen: '[userId]',
                initial: false,
                params: {
                  userId: message.user.id,
                },
              });

